# The route addition failed: The parameter is incorrect

Tags: windows, networking, routing

How can I null route a IP range? I get a parameter is incorrect error.

`route -p ADD 65.55.223.0-65.55.223.255 MASK 255.255.255.255 0.0.0.0`

`The route addition failed: The parameter is incorrect.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your [route](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490991.aspx) command syntax is wrong. Here is the proper syntax:

> Syntax
>
> route [-f] [-p] [Command [Destination] [mask Netmask] [Gateway]
>   [metric Metric]] [if Interface]]
>
> Destination   : Specifies the network destination of the route. The
>   destination can be an IP network address (where the host bits of the
>   network address are set to 0), an IP address for a host route, or
>   0.0.0.0 for the default route.

As you can see, the command doesn't allow adding ip range like that, and that's why you are getting the error. You need to define the range using network & netmask.

Null route doesn't necessarily means Routing to 0.0.0.0 it means actually Routing to nowhere or blackholing so that the packets are silently dropped.

You may try the following, where `if 1` stands for the loopback Interface:

```
route -p add 65.55.223.0 mask 255.255.255.0 Gateway_ip if 1
```

Alternatively, you can achieve similar result by pointing the gateway to an unused ip or a fake ip:

```
route -p add 65.55.223.0 mask 255.255.255.0 unused_ip_address
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrong network address used

Just got `The route addition failed: The parameter is incorrect.` error myself and it turns out I was using the wrong network address.

After struggling for a few minutes I turned to http://jodies.de/ipcalc which always saves the day when it comes to netmask calculations. (Unless there is a linux shell with Gentoos version of ipcalc available nearby)